# Link media images

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

We've transitioned to the media module for our Drupal 8 site. However, after extensive futzing, I can't figure out how to add a link to an embedded media image.

[image]

When you click on the media image, the image is highlighted, and you can right-click to get a menu. However, when I highlighted the image with a single-click, and then clicked on the link icon for the link dialog, the link was created just above the image.

[image]

I've also tried to click+drag my the cursor over the image, to highlight it (and whatever else I might get), and then use that multi-selected area, but I still get the same behavior.

How can I turn my media image into a clickable link?

**Edit** I thought this issue, [Linking media thumbnail image to internal/external url](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity/issues/2873754) might be about my situation. But, the patch (about a year old) doesn't apply anymore:

```
/core/modules/media 
$ patch -p1 < 2873754-8.patch
patching file src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/MediaThumbnailFormatter.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 11.
Hunk #2 succeeded at 66 (offset 4 lines).
Hunk #3 FAILED at 106.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 121.
Hunk #5 succeeded at 132 (offset 4 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 163 with fuzz 2 (offset 7 lines).
Hunk #7 FAILED at 177.
Hunk #8 succeeded at 214 with fuzz 2 (offset 14 lines).
4 out of 8 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/MediaThumbnailFormatter.php.rej
```

Comment: I typically add a link field on the media type - the entity browser should present a form that asks for those fields. Then I render the media object with the link wrapping the image. I haven't really found any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/issues/2511404), which has a series of patches and perhaps a module. I'm about to go into testing; perhaps-- hopefully-- coming out with a solution, but for now, there is not a clear solution.

**Edit** I applied [the patch from comment #47](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed/issues/2511404#comment-12584654), and it seems to work. At the time of writing, it's only 9 days old, but we're rolling with it since we need to link images.